# How to have two nested Parfors iterating over two huge arrays in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

Considering two arrays, `A=Huge_Arrau_one` and `B=Huge_array_two`, how can I change the following code to work in Matlab (as Matlab doesn't accept nested loops).

```
parfor (i,j) in all_combinations_of_A_and_B_indices

  A_in_this_worker = A(i);

  B_in_this_worker = B(j);

  ....
end
```

Please, note that I don't want to have all A and B array in memory for each worker as each worker just needs a tiny portion of that.
This problem has been discussed before for indexing two dimensions of a 2d array (using sub2ind and ind2sub functions ) but strangely enough, I've never seen this version of the problem I am currently struggling with.
In fact, I want to have a separate worker for each combination and I need to access a portion of both A and B in each worker.

Comment: Why not just use `ind2sub` here too? Define your loop header as `parfor ind = 1:(szA*szB)` ... then on the inside of the loop retrieve the indicies as `i,j = ind2sub([szA,szB],ind);`

Comment: Accessing A(i) and B(j) in this way causes Matlab to load the entire A and B for each worker.

Comment: I'm using MATLAB 2016b. I get a warning that accessing A and B like this "might result in unnecessary communication overhead" but when I check with `ticBytes`/`tocBytes` I find that isn't actually the case.

Comment: Did you analyze your memory consumption during the run?

Answer (score 0):

The [method Mathworks suggests](https://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/nested-parfor-loops-and-for-loops.html) is to use a parfor loop around a for loop
You might want to do it like:

```
parfor i = 1:length(Array_A)
    for j = 1:length(Array_B)
        % your code here
    end
end
```

Essentially, make sure you run the outer loop as a parfor loop

Comment: Thanks for the answer but actually I want a separate worker for each combination.

Comment: Do they both need to be done in the same nested loops? Or could they be done in two separate parfor loops

Comment: Hmmm, afraid I'm not sure what to do then. Sorry I couldn't be of more help!